# Should questions with trivial answers be deleted?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete, trivial

I recently asked two questions on Stack Overflow about Selenium tests that I thought were caused by interaction between Selenium and AJAX or JavaScript but turned out to be trivial syntax errors. In one issue it turned out that I had entered [an incorrect file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580404/selenium-pauses-indefinitely-when-clicking-on-html-button/15646013#15646013) when uploading a file on my web page. Since the answer ended up being unrelated to the original question I'm wondering if there is any point in leaving it on the site.

Comment: If you think it might help someone in the future then no.

Answer (score 2):

Your post got a Too Localized close vote, but the issue you brought up might happen to someone else, and it would be nice to know that a typo caused it (since Selenium appears to offer no meaningful feedback).

Comment: The issue I created might happen to someone else but is unlikely to be useful to people searching for selenium questions.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Is the issue something so localized that it is unlikely that it will ever help anyone else?

Then delete it.

Is the issue something that is likely to be a "gotcha" for someone else in the future?

Then keep it.

Err on the side of keeping. If the community thinks that it's way too trivial, it'll deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Someone else will make the same mistake you did, or something similar. Finding your question and seeing the "trivial" answer might inspire them to question their assumptions or not jump to a conclusion.

You really don't need to decide this on your own. Let the community decide whether it's worth keeping or not.

(It's probably too late to delete the question you linked anyway -- I don't think you can delete your own question if it has any answers.)

Comment: FYI you are prevented from deleting question if it has answers with a score of +1 or more.